# How to undeploy a bpel process using wso2 admin service

Tags: wso2, bpel

Is it possible to undeploy a bpel process using wso2 admin service?  If so, what is the name of the admin service that can do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For that you can use **BPELPackageManagementService**. You can view WSDL file for this service after changing **HideAdminServiceWSDLs** to false in carbon.xml. It is in `<BPS_HOME>`/repository/conf directory. You can view the wsdl file from the below link after restarting the server.

https://localhost:9443/services/BPELPackageManagementService?wsdl

You can use SOAP-UI to test this scenario. Please follow below steps.

1. Create SOAP-UI project using the above wsdl link.
2. Open **undeployBpelPackage** request and give your BPEL package name to undeploy.
3. In Auth tab configure basic authentication. (Username/password admin/admin - Authenticate Pre-emptively)

Now you will able to undeploy a given BPEL process using SOAP-UI.